# I have wc_doctor(doc_name,doc_id,dept_cd,const_fee)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the tables

```
wc_doctor(doc_name, doc_id, dept_cd, const_fee)
```

and

```
wc_patient(consl_id,patient_name,doc_id)
```

The query is supposed to display the name and number of patients for each doctor.

How can I do it?

I have written the following query:

```
SELECT 
  doc_name, 
  doc_id, 
  count(patient_name) 
FROM 
  wc_doctor LEFT JOIN wc_patient ON wc_doctor.doc_id =wc_patient.doc_id 
GROUP BY 
  doc_id
```

Comment: Just do `GROUP BY doc_name, doc_id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT doc_name, count(*) 
FROM wc_doctor a, wc_patient b
WHERE a.doc_id = b.doc_id 
GROUP BY doc_name;
```

Comment: Why not `GROUP BY doc_name`?